# ¿Cuándo se originó en España el término "montaña rusa"?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, etimología, expresiones, significado, españa

Conocemos aquí en España como "[montaña rusa](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monta%C3%B1a_rusa)" a una atracción de feria consistente en una serie de coches o vagones que se deslizan rápidamente por un sistema de raíles que forman una pista.

[image: Montaña rusa]
<sup>Montaña rusa Dragon Khan, en PortAventura Park (España).</sup>

Según el artículo enlazado de la Wikipedia, la montaña rusa "debe su nombre a las diversiones desarrolladas durante el invierno en Rusia, donde existían grandes toboganes de madera que se descendían con trineos deslizables sobre la nieve". También explica que "los primeros prototipos de montañas rusas eran trenes por gravedad con muchos cambios de rasante en la década de 1880".

Sin embargo, buscando un poco más de información, leo [el siguiente artículo](http://hemerotecadigital.bne.es/issue.vm?id=0004188495&page=275&search=%22monta%C3%B1a%20rusa%22&lang=es) en la hemeroteca de la Biblioteca Nacional, fechado en 1841:

> Habían levantado en aquel lugar para su diversión una enorme montaña rusa.

En [otro artículo](http://hemerotecadigital.bne.es/issue.vm?id=0026816614&page=1&search=%22monta%C3%B1a%20rusa%22&lang=es) de 1833 ya se habla de una montaña rusa situada en Madrid, en Buen-Retiro.

Así pues, ¿desde cuándo se conoce y usa en España el término "montaña rusa"? ¿Qué se conocía exactamente por aquel entonces como tal?

Comment: De hecho, la wikipedia en inglés ya menciona que _Russian Mountains were a predecessor to the roller coaster_ en su artículo [Russian Mountains](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Russian_Mountains). Y luego [Roller coaster](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roller_coaster) explica _The name Russian Mountains to designate a roller coaster is preserved in many Romance languages, such as the Spanish montaña rusa. However, the Russian term for roller coasters is "американские горки" ("amerikanskiye gorki"), which means "American Mountains"_.

Answer (score 4):

Las primeras "montañas rusas" se crearon en Rusia en pistas de hielo con subidas y bajadas, primero por personas anónimas en los alrededores de San Petersburgo, y el invento le gustó mucho a Catalina II la Grande, que mandó construir varias montañas rusas en sus jardines, y popularizaron bastante el término.

Los franceses se empezaron a referirse a ellas como montañas rusas (*montagnes russes*), y empezaron a usarlas en vías de tren, con vagones, y el término francés se entendió al español.

Curiosamente, en Rusia se llaman *Aмериканские горки (amerikanskie gorki)*, porque en EE.UU. se inventaron los primeros *roller coaster* (como se conocen a las montañas rusas en casi todo el mundo), que estaban montados como toboganes en tubos.

Comment: ¡Bienvenido a [Spanish.SE]! Tu respuesta tiene buena pinta, pero le falta algo. ¿Podrías dar fechas? ¿Tienes referencias que apoyen lo que dices? ¿Hay alguna imagen o dibujo de lo que podría ser una montaña rusa en aquella época? Cuanto más completa sea tu respuesta, más fácil será que la gente la vote y se que marque como la aceptada. Nótese que estoy interesado en saber cuándo se empezó a usar el término en España (y, como añadido, conocer la apariencia de las primeras montañas rusas de nuestro país).